# $.get json array duplicating

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax, json

This is my script for my products index. It produces the index of products multiple times which overlay each other. One layer is fixed and the other is scroll-able. Ive tried changing the the parameter etc but when i do I cant get the content to appear.

can anyone help me with this?

```
<h3 class="title">PRODUCTS</h3> <br><br><br><br>



<script>

$.getJSON("products2.php", function(data){
  $.each(data, function(i, field){
    $("DIV").append("<div class='productBox'>" + "id: " + field[0] + "<br> <b>" + "Name: "+ field[1] + "</b> <br>" +  "Description: " + field[2] + "<br>" + "Price: £" + field[3] + "<br>"+ "Stock: " + field[4] + "<br>" + "</div>");

  });
});


</script>


<?php include 'footer.php';?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a div with jQuery but not adding it to the DOM. Add a container to you html that you will store the products in, such as...

```
<div id="ProductsContainer"></div>
```

Then in your getJSON request callback you can clear the container and add your new products to it.

```
$('#ProductsContainer').html(''); //clear the html
$.each(data, function(i, field) {
    $('#ProductsContainer').append('your html'); //append new products
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to append field[0] and not something like this : field.id or data[i].id?